# Till when is the core web vitals INP calculated?

Tags: core-web-vitals, inp

When is the core web vitals INP calculated?

does it also include after the user navigates away from the page

The question is if a slow unload or beforeunload event also influences INP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is the core web vitals INP calculated?

INP should be calculated throughout the life of the page and then the worst INP (minus some extreme outliers) should be reported.

> does it also include after the user navigates away from the page
> The question is if a slow unload or beforeunload event also influences INP?

This gets tricky when there is no "next paint" opportunity on the page so currently Chrome does not measure these times (though they may be included in LCP of the next page). This is being discussed more here: https://github.com/w3c/event-timing/issues/129